# Mapping multiple objects to one object with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 6 properties in C Class and I want to map 3 of my properties from A method with output class A and 3 others from B method with output Class B

First, I map A to C (which is defined at `MappingProfile` class and 3 other properties are ignored) and then I map B to C (which has been defined like previous one)

My problem is that in the second Map my c object is always going to be override with b object and 3 other properties (which I got them from a object) come back as null (because they don't exist in B class).

In the end, I want to Have all data from a and b objects in my c object.

Mapping operations -

```
Adaptee Amethod = new Adaptee();
List<A> a = Amethod.A().ToList();
List<B> b = Amethod.B().ToList();
List<C> c1 = _mapper.Map<List<A>, List<C>>(a);
List<C> c = _mapper.Map(b, c1);
```

Mapping profiles -

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<A, C>()
        .ForMember(z => z.FN, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.FN))
        .ForMember(z => z.LN, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.LN))
        .ForMember(z => z.uniqe, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.uniqe))
        .ForMember(z => z.Addr, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(z => z.HomeTown, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(z => z.NID, opt => opt.Ignore());
        
    CreateMap<B, C>()
        .ForMember(z => z.Addr, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Addr))
        .ForMember(z => z.HomeTown, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.HomeTown))
        .ForMember(z => z.NID, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.NID))
        .ForMember(z => z.FN, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(z => z.LN, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(z => z.uniqe, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```

I'm using `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependancyInjection` v8.1.0.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your profile and mapping code. Are you still having the issue?

Comment: Yes,I am still having the issue

Answer (score -3):

you can use this method for multipli Object

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new sampleProfileMapper());
}).CreateMapper());
```

Comment: This code is assumed to be present in the question, because they already have a mapper and a profile.